# How to connect app container and redis container together on Docker on the same host?

Tags: python, docker, redis

I have folder **redis-docker**

File: **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        volumes:
            - ./config/redis.conf:/redis.conf
        command: [ "redis-server", "/redis.conf" ]
```

File: **redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

I have folder **test-redis**

File: **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

File: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM amd64/python:3

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
EXPOSE 6379

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

File: **requirements.txt**

```
redis
```

File: **test.py**

```
import redis

# connect to redis
client = redis.Redis(host=redis, port=6379)

# set a key
client.set('test-key', 'test-value')

# get a value
value = client.get('test-key')
print(value)
```

[image: Picture 1]

I execute 2 commands

```
docker-compose up
docker exec -it redis-docker_redis_1 redis-cli ping
```

and result like Pic2
[image: Picture 2]

Redis works great, but at this point I don't know how I can "test-redis" connect and use this "redis-docker". I spent more than 48 hours researching, but to no avail. I'm a Docker newbie. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: You have to make a SINGLE compose file with eighter the Redis and python app. Otherwise, each container has its own personal network [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: I know that, but now I want to make 2 separate containers

Comment: You can have one `docker-compose.yml` file that starts two containers.  That's a very normal setup.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question here for a few hours, I successfully found the solution myself. I will share it with everyone, so that people like me will save time in the future

Create 2 folder **"redis-docker"** and **"test-redis"**

1. The **"redis-docker"** folder will have the following files

File: **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        volumes:
            - ./config/redis.conf:/redis.conf
        command: [ "redis-server", "/redis.conf" ]
```

File: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

File: **redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

2. The **"test-redis"** folder will have the following files

File: **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

File: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM amd64/python:3

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
EXPOSE 6379

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

File: **requirements.txt**

```
redis
```

File: **test.py**

```
# connect to redis
client = redis.Redis(host='**you will have this parameter at the bottom**', port=6379)
# set a key
client.set('test-key', 'test-value')
# get a value
value = client.get('test-key')
print(value)
```

You upload the directory to your server, in this example I will upload the directory **/root/**. You execute the following commands

```
cd /root/redis-docker
docker build --no-cache . -t redisserverimg
docker run -it --rm --name B1 redisserverimg
```

**continue, you need to open a new CMD**

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

You will see like picture, save that IP **172.17.0.2**, and replace it in Python Code

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7Ye.png)

**continue, you need to open a new CMD**

```
cd /root/test-redis
docker build --no-cache . -t testredisimg
docker run -it --rm --name B2 testredisimg
```

and all done, runs great, 2 different containers. One is used to store data, the other to run Python. And you can use the command below to access the redis-cli of container B1

```
docker exec -it B1 redis-cli
```

**Thank you for reading. I hope this little sharing of mine will save you a whole day**

Comment: All of these commands when you simply can make a **single** [compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and have the same result?

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, my need is 2 different containers, if only 1 container I wouldn't ask it on here

Comment: I assume you haven't tried a single composition file, otherwise, you clearly see TWO different containers.

Comment: (This is the last comment and please be calmer). Please reread what I say: ONE Composefile == TWO Containers. Ask how to connect TWO containers: me and @DavidMaze say that this is a very common scenario on _compose_ and we invite you to read the documents about it, especially on networking (the problem you have). Starting the containers one by one (without specifying the network) gets the bridged network, instead starting the containers on a single composition file gets the same network.

Comment: Reading through this a couple of months later looking for a solution to a different problem and I really feel like the solution from the OP is an anti-pattern for docker. As far as I can tell, this is precisely the use-case for docker-compose where both services should be managed in one docker-compose file. The copy-pasting of IP addresses isn't really compatible with the containerised services approach, which is why a single docker-compose file would manage this for you.